# How to use maxWait, removeAbandonedTimeout and suspectTimeout attribute related to jdbc connection pooling

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, connection-pooling

I am using SQL server 2012, tomcat-7 to deploy my application and java 1.7.

My current configuration for connection pooling is, like

```
<Resource
    name="jdbc/devC"
    auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    maxActive="100"
    maxIdle="5"
    maxWait="-1"
    driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
    url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=DB_NAME"
    username="sa"
    password="db#123"
    removeAbandoned="true"
    removeAbandonedTimeout="300"
    logAbandoned="false"/>
```

In my application there are 7 different databases, so above configuration is also present for 7 different databases (These 7 databases are present on single server machine ).

With this configuration I am executing 80 threads, each thread utilize/uses one connection at a time. 
Now I need to improve my application execution, so I decided to increase threads from 80 to 150 or 200
But for that I need think about effect on connection pooling, So I need more understanding about it.

How can I use this attribute to improve my connection pooling, so that i can achieve faster execution by using more threads and connection pooling

1. How does removeAbandonedTimeout works ? Because I perform some demo on DB connection to check it behavior, but I didn't got anything.
2. How does suspectTimeout works ?
3. I have disabled maxWait by setting to -1,  is it the right way to use? I have disable it, Because my application sometime may reach the maxActive count.

Thank you in advance

Comment: what is wrong with the docs? https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html

Comment: By using this document is have perform configuration but at run time i didn't get actual understanding of behavior for this properties and also i am not able to track down effect done by this properties as they explained in document. for ex.  after removeAbandonedTimeout connection is removed, but in practical I observer the connection is working properly.

Comment: Unless a transaction has taken more than x amount of time, there will be no effect of `removeAbandonedTimeout`

Comment: Thank you for response, What If transaction takes x amount of then it will closed the connection or what it will do ?

Comment: *If set to true a connection is considered abandoned and eligible for removal if it has been in use longer than the removeAbandonedTimeout Setting this to true can recover db connections from applications that fail to close a connection*

Comment: Thank you and can you help in remaining like mapWait and suspectTimeout ?

Comment: Seems you didn't read the doc: _suspectTimeout: Get JMX notifications and log entries when connections are suspected for being abandoned. This is similar to the removeAbandonedTimeout but it doesn't take any action, only reports the information. This is achieved using the suspectTimeout attribute._